# previous link is empty after wordpress redirection

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to redirect the WordPress site from /invite to the homepage.

```
        if ( wp_redirect( '/' ) ) {
            exit();
        }
```

Which is working fine. The problem is on the homepage. The following code fails to read the previous link.

```
$prev_url = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : null; //returns null
```

or

```
$prev_url = wp_get_referer(); //returns false
```

I can see the redirection in the network tab of developer tools.

[image]

Can anyone help to rectify the issue? How to get the previous link?

Comment: Are you trying to redirect '/invite' to '/' while getting the previous on '/' page? or you try to get the ref_id value?

Comment: @HWSiew The first line of the question `I am trying to redirect the WordPress site from /invite to the homepage.`

Comment: which you had done it with wp_redirect( '/' ), no?

Comment: @HWSiew then read the 2nd line.. no?